# CAN-shield with MCP2515 on Raspberry Pi 4 B with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, can-bus

I would like to run a CAN shield with MCP2515 controller connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. It already worked under Raspbian but because I need ROS2 I want to run it under Ubuntu (20.04) now. Here it does not work anymore.

What I did was editing `/boot/config.txt` and adding the following lines:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=12000000,interrupt=25 
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835
```

But `ifconfig can` gives

```
can: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

The problem seems to be very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921924/raspberry-pi-spi-not-working-spi-bcm2835-not-showing-with-lsmod):
The `spi-bcm2835` module is not shown as output of `lsmod` and `dmesg` has this entry:

```
[    1.428843] spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
```

Is this a general problem of Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi? If so, is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ubuntu the boot partition is mounted under `/boot/firmware` with 3 files: config.txt, syscfg.txt, and usercfg.txt. The usercfg.txt is included by config.txt and is recommended to bearing user customized configuration. So saving your lines in usercfg.txt instead should make it works

[usercfg.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pw10.png)

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apK7J.png)

[candump by can-utils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XECWS.png)

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain the actual text of the code being posted. [Do not post code using pictures](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was indeed the problem.